# Router activeClassName in ReactJS not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

I have a problem with router activeClassName in my React App. 
I set my routes correctly, everything works fine. I appended activeClassName rule, when i inspect link elements they should toggle className on click, that is how activeClassName should work, but that is the problem. When i click on link element nothing happens, it do not recognize activeClassName rule, no class is applyed.

Here are the code snippets.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import classes from './Classes.module.css'
const navigation =(props)=>{
      return(
            <div>
                <NavLink activeClassName={classes.Active} exact to="/">HOME</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeClassName={classes.Active} exact to="/about">ABOUT</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeClassName={classes.Active} exact to="/contact">CONTACT</NavLink>   
            </div>
)}
```

CSS

```
.Active{
     background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink `activeClassName` is a string. Have you checked what the value and type of `classes.Active` is? Can you simply do `<NavLink activeClassName="Active"...`?

Comment: I checked that out, it is the string, i get the same result when i use pure css instead of css modules. So that is not the solution.

Comment: Are your styles imported and applied in your app? [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-navigation-navlink-active-class-x36wi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) I've not come across this way of styling react components, but typically in react you import a css file and apply a `className` prop, use a `style` prop object, or a styling/theme package/library that does this.